# Default Eclipse Configuration (VM, Classpath) for JUNIT?

Tags: eclipse

I have default configurations such as VM arguments (-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M) as well as class path folders to run the all the JUNIT 
test cases.

Currently in eclipse i'm always creating the same/duplicate configuration for each test case else the test cases were failed.

Is there is a way to configure the above as default for all JUNIT test cases to avoid  creating a duplicate of existing test case and renaming the test case name?

The reason is whenever i need to run a new test case i need to do the above operations. If there is a way then the Junit test cases will automatically picks the default configuration and the test case will run automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set default VM arguments in the eclipse preferences which will be used for every run configuration, so you don't even have to set them for your application:

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Installed JRE` -> Select your active JRE and click `Edit`. Put your arguments for `Default VM Arguments`.

Comment: @Kathir you should try that but I'm sure the Default VM Arguments will apply here too.

Comment: Any way to set these arguments only for the Junit JRE and not for every process launched by Eclipse? Modifying Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE also modifies the runtime args for tomcat and any other app i launch with Eclipse.

Comment: @vanval you can set these values for the run configuration of your unit test also.

Comment: @user714965 I wanted a way to set it at a higher level same as for the question above - I want to avoid having to set it in the run configuration for every unit test and at the same time avoid it taking effect for every java process launched from eclipse which would happen if I set it on the JRE

Comment: meh yeah we want more control than taht